# Call a class after clicking on button in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I call a particular class when clicking on a button  ?
So far ,
My jQuery code is :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.btn').click(function () {     
      //script to call a class   
   });  
   })
```

Now I have a html class . What i need is to call that class when i click a button .

```
<div class="page-loader-wrapper">
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="preloader">
            <div class="spinner-layer pl-red">
                <div class="circle-clipper left">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="circle-clipper right">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Please wait...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: what do you mean by call a class? select a class? `$('.classname')`?

Comment: @Mr Programmer. Which class you wanted to target???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  //script to call a class  
  var myClass =  $(".page-loader-wrapper");
  
  // display the class or whatever
 myClass.toggle();
  
  //if you mean calling a function instead of class it can be done like this.
  myFunction();
  
});

// test function
function myFunction(){
  console.log("This is a test...");
}
```

```css
.page-loader-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='btn'>PRESS ME</button>
<br>
To access a class and modifiy it you just need to reference the class name and then you can do stuff with it. Like this: 
<pre>
 var myClass =  $(".page-loader-wrapper");
 myClass.toggle();
</pre>
<div class="page-loader-wrapper">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="preloader">
      <div class="spinner-layer pl-red">
        <div class="circle-clipper left">
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-clipper right">
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Please wait...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to html elements by using jquery add class method

```
$("p").addClass("intro");
```

where p is the selector and intro is the class name.